# Ruby - how to select one random character from two ranges

Tags: ruby

I have two ranges - 97..122 and 49..57
(they are the letters and the numbers).
I can do, for example rand(97..122).chr to get a random letter.

If I want a digit to be either or numbers how can I do that?
Something like `rand([97..122, 49..57]).chr`
But I am not sure how to add the ranges together - rand takes a range, but  doesn't take that.

Comment: `[*97..122, *49..57].sample` ?

Answer (score 4):

Numbers 0-9 and all letters, that is how numbers are represented in base 36:

```
rand(36).to_s(36)
```

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to avoid the creation of array.

**#1**

```
rand(35).yield_self {|rn| rn + (rn < 10 ? 49 : 87)}.chr
```

Note:

```
35 = 57-48 + 122-96
```

and

```
10 = 58-48
```

**#2 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯**

```
"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[rand 36]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform range to array:

```
((97..122).to_a + (49..57).to_a).sample.chr
```

or

```
(Array(97..122) + Array(49..57)).sample.chr
```

or

```
([*97..122] + [*49..57]).sample.chr
```

Comment: ...or `(('97'..'122').to_a + ('49'..'57').to_a).sample`. This has the disadvantage of creating two temporary arrays that are discarded.

Comment: Yes, but @Michael wanted `#chr` method, so he need `Integer`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with conditional sampling:

```
rand <= 26r / 35 ? rand(97..122).chr : rand(49..57).chr
```

which avoids an array at the cost of drawing an additional random value. 26 is the length of the first range, 35 is the combined lengths of both ranges, so 26 out of 35 times you're drawing values from the first range, the rest of the time from the second.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe sampling from an array containing two random numbers generated from the ranges?
For weighting the probability, since 26/9≈3:

```
([rand(97..122)]*3 << rand(49..57)).sample.chr
```

Comment: If you agree #1 is incorrect consider keeping only #2. To be accurate: `[*[rand(97..122)]*26, *[rand(49..57)]*10].sample.chr`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, removed the incorrect. But I supposed to avoid the creation of an array of 35. `(49..57)` should contain 9 elements. Do you know if there is a different way to weight the random between two numbers? Maybe in the random class itself?

Comment: Ah, yes, `9`. No, I don't know about that.